# Best performance Javascript conditionals based on countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, timer

I am currently working on a project that is showing and displaying `DOM` elements based on a countdown timer.  There is another function calling this one every second.

Here is a code sample:

```
function eventsOnTimer() {

  let x = 1;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {

    if (x >= 0.0 && x < 30.0) {
      document.getElementById('thing1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('thing2').style.display = 'none';
    } 

    else if (x >= 30.0 && x < 60.0) {
      document.getElementById('thing1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('thing2').style.display = 'block';
    }

    x++;

  }, 1000);

}
```

I'm trying to increase performance, and I'm doing this by trying to reduce the number of `DOM` requests and looking at alternative ways to fire code based on the countdown timer.

Comment: Cache the DOM lookups (the results of the calls to `.getElementById()`).

Comment: Are you sure this is really a bottleneck? 2 DOM changes every second is pretty trivial.

Comment: CSS not an option?

Comment: @Malk I was thinking something similar, but it's not obvious that changing a class and then looking up the CSS for the class is better than just changing the style directly. I'm not even sure how to benchmark it, since it's asynchronous browser rendering.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I have cached the DOM lookups that are not unique each time.

Comment: I mean CSS animations. You can easily set the styles to flip based on time.

Comment: I wonder why you're running the function every second, but then using `if()` statements so it only changes things every 30 seconds.

Comment: @Barmar this is just a sample,  maybe up to 10 items at a time.  The code runs every second.  The `if (x >= 0.0 && x < 30.0)` means that code block would run every second between 0 and 29.

Comment: Don't get it - why do you need to call the function every second when you're testing if 30 seconds has gone past? Also why are you testing if x > 0 and for decimals?

Comment: @Booboobeaker The if statements are testing a timer.  The page needs to be in a state between 0-29.  The dom is updated to that state.  Then the timer reaches 30 and is changed to the second code block.

Comment: Yes i can see that, but why not just run the code block once every 30 seconds

Comment: Do you have another step? (ex : x > 60)

Comment: @Booboobeaker are you saying instead of running `if (x >= 0.0 && x < 30.0)` I run `if (x = 0)` and  `if (x = 30)` to trigger the dom changes?

Comment: @ThibaultBach Yes indeed.  I provide this as an example, the idea is to create events that happen at certain times, they could change.

Comment: I'll answer as an answer, please go ahead delete if it's not what you wanted

Comment: @Booboobeaker Good answer and I think you made the (reasonable) assumption that I'm bound to the variables in the conditional statements, however I still need the resolution to be able to make changes by the second.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
function eventsOnTimer(id1, id2, ms) {
  let toggle = false, thing1 = document.getElementById(id1), thing2 = document.getElementById(id2);

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(toggle){
        thing1.style.display = 'block';
        thing2.style.display = 'none';
      } else{
        thing1.style.display = 'none';
        thing2.style.display = 'block';
      }
      toggle = !toggle;
  }, ms);
}

eventsOnTimer('thing1', 'thing2', 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all of nodes references before run your timer to dicrease DOM access time (getElementById).

After that, using className instead of style property will be faster. You juste need declared an specific CSS rule per state.

I propose to you an generic function to set automatically all of your nodes with the same CSS class name.

**JS**

```
var nodeArray = [];
var max_node = 2; 

function storeNodeRef() {
 for(var i =1; i <= max_node; i++) {
  nodeArray.push( document.getElementById("thing"+i)); // Your nodes are declared with ID thing"X". "X" is a numeric value, set "max_node"  with the latest "X" value.
 }
  eventsOnTimer();
}

function setNodeClass(nodeClassName) {
  var i = 0;
  while(i < max_node) {
    nodeArray[i++].className = nodeClassName;
  }

}

function eventsOnTimer() {
  let x = 1;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (x==30 || x == 60) { // declare here your different state, you can use multiple if/elseif or multiple switch case.
      setNodeClass('hide myClass'+x); // Param : new className
    } 
    x++;
  }, 1000);
}

 storeNodeRef();
```

**CSS**

```
  .process > div, .hide {display:none;}
  #thing2.myClass30, #thing1.myClass60, .process > div.show {display:block; }
```

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
<div class="process">
    <div id="thing1" class="show" >Hello World 1</div>
    <div id="thing2">Hello World  2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no evidence that setting a class name is any faster than setting a style. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693719/javascript-performance-of-classname-changes-vs-style-changes

Comment: I know isn't always true but globaly with a large chose of browsers classname is fastest than style property. It's not a big difference but if you managed lot of node you can saved time.